# cannot import name 'theano_backend' from 'keras.backend'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, theano

I am trying to run the following:

```
from keras.backend import theano_backend
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-64-39e623866e51>", line 1, in <module>
    from keras.backend import theano_backend

ImportError: cannot import name 'theano_backend' from 'keras.backend' (C:\Users\Dr. Sunil Singla\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py)
```

I cloned this repo: https://github.com/titu1994/DenseNet.git and attempted to run it on my image data.

Comment: I cloned this repo: https://github.com/titu1994/DenseNet.git and attempted to run it on my image data.

Comment: Which version of Keras are you using?

Comment: I am using keras 2.4.3

Comment: Please help anyone

Answer (score 0):

The latest Keras versions are just a wrapper on top of tf.keras, they are not the multi-backend keras you are expecting.

For this code to work, you should downgrade Keras to a version that is still multi-backend, like 2.2.x versions. I think 2.3.x still have multiple backends too, but versions 2.4 are TensorFlow only.